# How to write a function that checks if elements in a file are repeated?

Tags: python, file

I have a file "f.txt" and in it I have a lot of numbers in the form of type str. Each number has a maximum of 9 digits and a minimum of 3. Each number is separated by a new line character (so each number is in its own line, I don't know how to properly format that so the examples down below isn't accurate in term of formatting).

I want to write a function that loops through the file and checks if there are any numbers in that file that is repeated. The inside of the file looks like this:

1244816 \n
2760125 \n
1102758 \n
713765 \n
6521147 \n
4711995 \n
1494276 \n 
12336119 \n 
8398120 \n 
1215092 \n 
8125139 \n
...

```
with open("ket.txt") as f:
line = f.readline()
status = True
while status:
    if line == #looping through the entire file to see if there is
               #identical number:
        status = False
```

I have some pseudo code? I'm not sure how I can achieve the comment part though.

Comment: Have you got any code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say I have a file `f.txt` containing:

```
12324
41564
7754564654654
123
87642
123
89745312
```

Then the following python script, let's call it `scan.py`:

```
def main():
    with open('f.txt', 'r') as f:
        numbers_seen = set()
        for n in f:
            if n in numbers_seen:
                print('{} appears more than once!'.format(n.strip()))
                return
            numbers_seen.add(n)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

then running `python scan.py` will produce:

```
123 appears more than once!
```